# How many integers are there between $1$ and $2011$ inclusive that are multiples of $6$ or $7$ or $9$ but not $12$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many integers are there between $1$ and $2011$ inclusive that are multiples of $6$ or $7$ or $9$ but not $12$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Are you familiar with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: I have found the number of integers that are multiples of 6 or 7 or 9 through PIE, but not sure how to remove those integers that are multiples of 12.

Comment: When I looked at the simpler example of finding the number of integers from $1$ through $100$ that are multiples of $6$ or $7$ or $9$ but not $12$, I found $33$ numbers that  are multiples of $6$ or $7$ or $9$, $8$ numbers that are multiples of $12$, and $25$ numbers that are multiples of $6$ or $7$ or $9$ but not $12$.  I found that if I listed the multiples of $6$, $7$, and $9$ in that order, then struck out the duplicates, I left the list of multiples of $6$ untouched until I struck out the multiples of $12$.  Clearly, this is not a formal proof, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use inclusion exclusion principle ie Total integers=multiples of $6$+multiples of $7$ +multiples of $9$-multiples of $12$

Comment: Be careful.  You have to account for the fact that there are numbers less than $2011$ that are multiplies of both $6$ and $7$, both $6$ and $9$, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\lfloor2011/a\rfloor+\lfloor2011/b\rfloor-\lfloor2011/\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\rfloor$ is the count of all integers in $[1,2011]$ which are multiples of $a$ or $b$.

$\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ is supposed to be the *lowest common multiple* of $a$ and $b$.

The final count/result is $504$.